# Why am I only getting 10 rows from postgres using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, postgresql

There is a task to get some rows from the postgresql database, from VBA.
I make a request with my hands and I know for sure that there are ~ 200 rows in the table. But if I make it a VBA script, then UBound says that I have only 10 lines in the record and trying to access line 11 causes an out of range error.
I am sure that there are more than 10 lines and there are more than 10 in LIMIT, but there are always 10 lines.
Yes, I can do it with OFFSET, but I want to reduce the number of queries.

```
Sub main()

Dim query As String

'Create Connection
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strCnx = "Driver={PostgreSQL Unicode};Server=10.84._._;Port=5432;Database=_;UID=_;PWD=_;"
conn.Open strCnx

'Query the Database
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rs.Open "SELECT id, FROM dbo.orders ORDER BY tid DESC LIMIT 100", conn
Record = rs.GetRows()
Worksheets("index").Columns("A").ClearContents
Cells(1, 1) = Record(0, 10)
rs.Close
```

Comment: After the line `Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")` add `rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient`. Does that solve it? Also note that with `Cells(1, 1) = Record(0, 10)` you are always writing just the first ten rows to your worksheet.

Comment: What does Record(0, 10) do?

Comment: @Frank `Record(0,10)` would be the first field of the 11th record. I guess this where the error occurs,

Comment: Try `Cells(1,1).CopyFromRecordset rs` after `rs.open`

Comment: @Nick Your profession is something like a sorcerer? I added the line `rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient` , got an error that I didn't have some component installed, commented it out and now everything works.
But why it works - now I do not know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
```